# Ubuntu 16.04.2 Terminals Getting Stuck

Tags: 16.04

The issue is that sometimes when I open a terminal and try to do any command (ls, ping, top, touch, etc), it just hangs. It is also unresponsive to ctrl+c or ctrl+z.  This also happens when I go to the ctrl+alt+f1 terminal.  Any tips would be appreciated.  I don't know how to reproduce this on-demand.

It seems to happen more often when I wake up my computer from sleep.  I am still able to open apps from the search menu, including htop, but I'm not sure what to look for there.  I've tried searching around for other people with this issue but I haven't been able to figure out the right thing to search.

I've had this issue for about a year now and its one of those things that is really frustrating when it happens and I am motivated to fix it, but it only lasts about 2 minutes at most and then goes away for days without really getting fixed.  I usually open a bunch of terminals and eventually they all pop to life at the same time.

Here is the result of dmesg shortly after the hang (I'm not exactly sure when it started/stopped hanging)

```
[166117.252126] audit: type=1400 audit(1524765487.010:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mimeinfo.cache" pid=18314 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[166371.391498] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166371.391532] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166371.391557] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166371.439628] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166371.439643] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166371.439653] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166371.461246] wlp58s0: deauthenticating from b0:7f:b9:43:2d:6c by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[166371.773438] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[166371.780329] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[166374.416870] [drm] Reducing the compressed framebuffer size. This may lead to less power savings than a non-reduced-size. Try to increase stolen memory size if available in BIOS.
[166374.467543] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[166374.469871] OOM killer disabled.
[166374.469873] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[166374.471024] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[166374.471063] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[166376.092952] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1405.638 msecs
[166376.114813] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 21.854 msecs
[166376.154925] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 40.105 msecs
[166376.155854] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[166376.199291] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[166376.199292] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[166376.199293] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[166376.199415] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[166376.216575] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[166376.239556] irq_migrate_all_off_this_cpu: 5 callbacks suppressed
[166376.239559] IRQ 123: no longer affine to CPU2
[166376.239567] IRQ 124: no longer affine to CPU2
[166376.239625] IRQ 281: no longer affine to CPU2
[166376.239635] IRQ 286: no longer affine to CPU2
[166376.241721] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[166376.263329] IRQ 1: no longer affine to CPU3
[166376.263338] IRQ 8: no longer affine to CPU3
[166376.263346] IRQ 9: no longer affine to CPU3
[166376.263355] IRQ 12: no longer affine to CPU3
[166376.263362] IRQ 14: no longer affine to CPU3
[166376.263372] IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU3
[166376.264471] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[166376.268332] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[166376.268447] ACPI: EC: EC started
[166376.268448] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[166376.269254] Suspended for 336.976 seconds
[166376.269334] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[166376.269394] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[166376.269395] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[166376.269985]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[166376.270155] CPU1 is up
[166376.270213] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[166376.270724]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[166376.270886] CPU2 is up
[166376.270919] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[166376.271397]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[166376.271627] CPU3 is up
[166376.274999] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[166377.311295] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 462.007 msecs
[166377.325881] PM: early resume of devices complete after 14.503 msecs
[166377.326050] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[166377.389877] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 3 resume PLC timeout
[166377.408207] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 2 resume PLC timeout
[166377.557232] [drm] Reducing the compressed framebuffer size. This may lead to less power savings than a non-reduced-size. Try to increase stolen memory size if available in BIOS.
[166377.647646] usb 1-4: reset full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[166377.907792] usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[166378.167654] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[166378.387682] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[166378.489769] PM: resume of devices complete after 1163.881 msecs
[166378.490084] usb 1-3:1.0: rebind failed: -517
[166378.490091] usb 1-3:1.1: rebind failed: -517
[166378.490910] acpi LNXPOWER:13: Turning OFF
[166378.491245] acpi LNXPOWER:12: Turning OFF
[166378.491504] acpi LNXPOWER:11: Turning OFF
[166378.491762] acpi LNXPOWER:10: Turning OFF
[166378.492018] acpi LNXPOWER:0f: Turning OFF
[166378.492273] acpi LNXPOWER:0e: Turning OFF
[166378.492528] acpi LNXPOWER:0d: Turning OFF
[166378.492787] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
[166378.493041] acpi LNXPOWER:0b: Turning OFF
[166378.493296] acpi LNXPOWER:0a: Turning OFF
[166378.493574] acpi LNXPOWER:09: Turning OFF
[166378.493830] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
[166378.494086] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[166378.494345] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
[166378.494602] acpi LNXPOWER:05: Turning OFF
[166378.494855] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
[166378.495127] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
[166378.495383] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
[166378.495637] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[166378.495892] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
[166378.496068] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[166378.496071] OOM killer enabled.
[166378.496072] Restarting tasks ... done.
[166378.618166] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp58s0: link is not ready
[166378.940787] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
[166378.940795] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x138, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[166378.968680] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
[166379.343548] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[166379.346604] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[166379.388864] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp58s0: link is not ready
[166379.407371] [drm] RC6 on
[166379.440208] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp58s0: link is not ready
[166379.952094] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify:481 (dev=-1) Notifying crtc state: 3
[166379.952096] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_send_crtc_state:387 Painter is not connected!
[166379.952101] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166379.952113] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify:481 (dev=-1) Notifying crtc state: 3
[166379.952114] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_send_crtc_state:387 Painter is not connected!
[166379.952123] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166379.952132] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify:481 (dev=-1) Notifying crtc state: 3
[166379.952133] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_send_crtc_state:387 Painter is not connected!
[166379.952136] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166380.105519] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166380.105533] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166380.105542] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
[166402.057381] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp58s0: link is not ready
[166405.543384] wlp58s0: authenticate with a0:3d:6f:a5:12:ef
[166405.584850] wlp58s0: send auth to a0:3d:6f:a5:12:ef (try 1/3)
[166405.585648] wlp58s0: authenticated
[166405.587003] wlp58s0: associate with a0:3d:6f:a5:12:ef (try 1/3)
[166405.590492] wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from a0:3d:6f:a5:12:ef (capab=0x101 status=0 aid=189)
[166405.592849] wlp58s0: associated
[166405.592904] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp58s0: link becomes ready
[166405.595566] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
[166405.595567] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[166405.595568] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[166405.595568] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[166405.595569] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[166405.595569] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[166405.595570] ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country IE
[166405.595790] wlp58s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by a0:3d:6f:a5:12:ef
[166578.734559] nfs: server whirlpool.stanford.edu not responding, timed out
[166619.694502] nfs: server whirlpool.stanford.edu not responding, timed out
[166627.099190] mmap: avahi-daemon (864): VmData 4210688 exceed data ulimit 4194304. Update limits or use boot option ignore_rlimit_data.
```